# "merge" two tables -from different databases- together?

Tags: postgresql, merge

Well say I have a table running on a database at localhost (donor database A), and a receiving table running at another server externally (database B) With table creation (on both sides) like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    key text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE public.my_table_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE public.my_table ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.language_dictionary_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Now I wish to merge from database A into database B. *However* only merging should happen on keys that are not existing on database B, and id should be recalculated (obviously to not have duplicates).

Basically as if each row from database A is insert into database B using:

```
INSERT INTO public.my_table (key, description)
VALUES (...)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

Comment: are the databases on thbe same server? even then make a backup from database A and import into B

Comment: no? They are aon different servers. "I have a table running on a database at localhost (donor database A), and a receiving table running at another server externally "

Comment: @nbk what do you mean? Can you explain "zjrm try z"

Comment: make a backup dump on server A and import it as file in Server B(localhost)

Comment: @nbk but how do I prevent it from overwriting the table data? - And if I go through a temporary table, how do I make sure the ids are correctly set up?

Comment: as you have no constraints (uniqueness) it will add all columns

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL there is a MERGE statement that meets your requirements.
PostgreSQL has the same.
Read more: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

It allows full control about conditions when to add a row, update a row or delete a row in the target db. I have frequently used it. But it is not a high performance operation if used with a lot of rows.

Of course you need to take care for a direct connection between the servers running the databases.

Sample:

```
MERGE CustomerAccount CA
USING (SELECT CustomerId, TransactionValue, 
   FROM Transactions
   WHERE TransactionId > 35345678) AS T
ON T.CustomerId = CA.CustomerId
WHEN MATCHED 
  UPDATE SET Balance = Balance - TransactionValue
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  INSERT (CustomerId, Balance)
  VALUES (T.CustomerId, T.TransactionValue)
;
```

Comment: You cannot do this between different databases. Generally options are using FDW , Logical Replication or Dump - Restore